# Writing a Taste test program for C++ not incrementing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a taste test program for a class and it will run fine up until my if statements. However, once I get into my if statements it isn't incrementing i, so it never leaves the while loop.

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int q = 0;
    int p = 0;
    int c = 0;
    char preference;
    int x = 0;
    cout << "How many taste tests would you like to do?" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    while (i<x)
    {
        cout << "Do you prefer Coke, Pepsi, or are they the same? Use c for coke, p for pepsi, and q for the same\n";
        cin >> preference;
        if (preference == 'q' || preference == 'Q')
        {
            q = q + 1;
            i++;
        }
        if (preference == 'p' || preference == 'P')
        {
            p = p + 1;
            i++;
        }
        if (preference == 'c' || preference == 'C')
        {
            c = c + 1;
            i++;
        }

    }
    if (p>q)
    {
        cout << "Pepsi wins" << endl;
        if (c>p)
            cout << "Coke wins" << endl;
        if (c == p)
            cout << "Tie" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger, and step through the code starting with `cin >> preference;` and see what happens as you step through the code.

Comment: I think that you are trying to do something like that `if(preference=='q' || preference=='Q')` you didn't put the `'`

Comment: do they teach debugging in CS classes? Seems like they dont.

Comment: your variables `p`, `P`, `q`, etc. are `0`, so while this compiles, it does not test if there is a match like you think it does. Also sure I've seen this kind of mistake before, but not sure if I could find the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to check if the a determined char was clicked by `cin >> preference` but you are test `int` vars, so if i press 'q'

```
//if(preference==q || preference==Q) // 'q'==0 || 'p'==0
if(preference=='q' || preference=='Q') // 'q'=='q' || 'q'=='Q'
```

so add `''`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines in the code for the expected behavior.

```
//if(preference==q || preference==Q)
if(preference=='q' || preference=='Q'

//if(preference==p || preference==P)
if(preference=='p' || preference=='P')

//if(preference==c || preference==C)
if(preference=='c' || preference=='C')
```